# Android SDK Ubuntu default path

Tags: android, sdk, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to build my Android app in Unity on `Ubuntu`, but cannot find Android `SDK`.
What is Android `SDK` default path on `Ubuntu`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Path will be like,

> Linux /home/AccountName/Android/Sdk

- For Linux: ~/Android/Sdk
- For Mac: ~/Library/Android/sdk
- For Windows: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk

Comment: For my case on Ubuntu 16.04, it's ~/Android/Sdk

Answer (score 51):

If you've installed the SDK using:

```
apt install android-sdk
```

it is located at `/usr/lib/android-sdk`.

Answer (score 6):

If you've installed the SDK using the `apt install android-sdk`, it is located at `/usr/lib/android-sdk`

then copy that folder (android-sdk) to your home folder ex: home/username/Android/android-sdk, because /usr/lib/android-sdk will prompt a not writable error..by default there's no Android folder in your home directory so create that folder first then paste inside it the android-sdk folder from /usr/lib

Answer (score 4):

If you installed it using `sudo apt install android-sdk` it should be in `/usr/lib/`.

Comment: What was the point in duplicating my answer? No new info here.

Answer (score 3):

It should be in your home folder under `Android/Sdk`folder, i.e., `~/Android/Sdk`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to answer, but this would clarify some of the confusions.

- If you installed the SDK through the Ubuntu terminal using the command `sudo apt install android-sdk` it will be located at `/usr/lib/android-sdk/`
- If you installed the Android SDK through the Android Studio it will be located at `/home/<AccountName>/Android/Sdk`

Note that both these are the paths for Ubuntu